# Equation. Proof that there is no solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\nexists x,y \in \mathbb{N} $ such that:
$$\begin{cases} x -y - 3k -1 = 0 \\ x-y -4l -2 =0 \\ x+y - 3f - 2 =0\\ x + y - 5m - 2 = 0 \\ x,y \in \mathbb{N} \end{cases} $$
I'm asking form any advice. 
Please help me :)

Comment: What are $k,l,f$ and $m$? Also, the second equation: shouldn't it be $x-y-4l-2=0$?

Comment: Does the second equation have a typo or is there 1 more equation there?

Comment: I edited a post.

Comment: If $x=1=y$ then $f=0,\,m=0,\,k=-1/3,\,l=-1/2$. Again.. what are $k,l,f,m$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f=10,m=6,l=2,k=3$ then the system is

\begin{cases} x -y = 10 \\ x-y =10 \\ x+y =32 \\ x + y  = 32  \end{cases}

that has $x=21,y=11$ as solution.